# How To Prevent AWS Lambda Abuse by 3rd-party apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless

Very interested in getting hands-on with **[Serverless](https://serverless.com/)** in 2018. Already looking to implement usage of **[AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)** in several decentralized app projects. However, I don't yet understand how you can prevent abuse of your endpoint from a 3rd-party app *(perhaps even a competitor),* from driving up your usage costs.

I'm not talking about a DDoS, or where all the traffic is coming from a single IP, which can happen on any network, but specifically having a 3rd-party app's customers directly make the REST calls, which cause your usage costs to rise, because their app is piggy-backing on your **"open"** endpoints.

**For example:**

I wish to create an endpoint on AWS Lambda to give me the **[current price of Ethereum ETH/USD.](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#price-tickers)** What would prevent another *(or every)* dapp developer from using **MY** lambda endpoint and causing excessive billing charges to my account?

Comment: It's API Gateway that is open to the public, not your Lambda function. The better question would be "How to prevent API Gateway abuse by 3rd-party apps?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you deploy an endpoint that is open to the world, you're opening it to be used, but also to be abused.

AWS provides services to avoid common abuse methods, such as AWS Shield, which mitigates against DDoS, etc., however, they do not know what is or is not abuse of your Lambda function, as you are asking.

If your Lambda function is private, then you should use one of the API gateway security mechanisms to prevent abuse:

- IAM security
- API key security
- Custom security authorization

With one of these in place, your Lambda function can only by called by authorized users. Without one of these in place, there is no way to prevent the type of abuse you're concerned about.

Comment: What does Amazon recommend when integrating Lambda into a mobile app (eg. React Native)? AFAIK, api keys should never be placed directly into source code. I'm not at all familiar with IAM.

Comment: Never hard code API keys into your source code. Instead, your users should get an API key from you to use with your app. So each user would have a unique key. This allows you to disable keys if needed, and it avoids hard coding credentials into your app. It also prevents a competitor from getting hold of the single API key and using it.

Comment: So how would an app user "directly" access a Serverless function, if they don't have the API key is really my question?

Comment: Without proper security authorization, they cannot access your serverless function. You would give access only to those that should be using the function.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice. I'll probably start with understanding `IAM security` and then take it from there.

Comment: It is not always enough, it's just a start to add such mechanisms. I'm getting abused by an authorised 3rd party API that is sending me tons of calls instead of 1, because something is misconfigured in their system. I have a token auth mechanism, but it doesn't help at all here. It does protect me from external unauthorized callers though.

Answer (score 5):

Unlimited access to your public Lambda functions - either by bad actors, *or* by bad software developed by legitimate 3rd parties, can result in unwanted usage of billable corporate resources, and can degrade application performance. It is important to you consider ways of limiting and restricting access to your Lambda clients as part of your systems security design, to prevent runaway function invocations and uncontrolled costs.

**Consider using the following approach to preventing execution "abuse" of your Lambda endpoint by 3rd party apps**:

One factor you want to control is concurrency, or number of concurrent requests that are supported per account and per function. You are [billed per request plus total memory allocation per request](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/), so this is the unit you want to control. To prevent run away costs, you prevent run away executions - either by bad actors, or by bad software cause by legitimate 3rd parties.

From [Managing Concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html)

> The unit of scale for AWS Lambda is a concurrent execution (see
>   Understanding Scaling Behavior for more details). However, scaling
>   indefinitely is not desirable in all scenarios. For example, you may
>   want to control your concurrency for cost reasons, or to regulate how
>   long it takes you to process a batch of events, or to simply match it
>   with a downstream resource. To assist with this, Lambda provides a
>   concurrent execution limit control at both the account level and the
>   function level.

In addition to per account and per Lambda invocation limits, you can also control Lambda exposure by wrapping Lambda calls in an AWS API Gateway, and Create and Use API [Gateway Usage Plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html):

> After you create, test, and deploy your APIs, you can use API Gateway
>   usage plans to extend them as product offerings for your customers.
>   You can provide usage plans to allow specified customers to access
>   selected APIs at **agreed-upon request rates and quotas** that can meet
>   their business requirements and budget constraints.
>
> What Is a Usage Plan? A usage plan prescribes who can access one or
>   more deployed API stages— and also h**ow much and how fast the caller
>   can access the APIs.** The plan uses an API key to identify an API
>   client and meters access to an API stage with the configurable
>   throttling and quota limits that are enforced on individual client API
>   keys.
>
> The t**hrottling prescribes the request rate limits that are applied to
>   each API key.** The quotas are the maximum number of requests with a
>   given API key submitted within a specified time interval. You can
>   configure individual API methods to require API key authorization
>   based on usage plan configuration. An API stage is identified by an
>   API identifier and a stage name.

Using [API Gateway Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) to create [Gateway Usage Plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) per customer, you can control API and Lambda access prevent uncontrolled account billing.

Answer (score 5):

@Matt answer is correct, yet incomplete.

Adding a security layer is a necessary step towards security, but doesn't protect you from authenticated callers, as @Rodrigo's answer states.

I actually just encountered - and solved - this issue on one of my lambda, thanks to this article: https://itnext.io/the-everything-guide-to-lambda-throttling-reserved-concurrency-and-execution-limits-d64f144129e5

Basically, I added a single line on my `serverless.yml` file, in my function that gets called by the said authirized 3rd party:

```
reservedConcurrency: 1
```

And here goes the whole function:

```
refresh-cache:
    handler: src/functions/refresh-cache.refreshCache
    # XXX Ensures the lambda always has one slot available, and never use more than one lambda instance at once.
    #  Avoids GraphCMS webhooks to abuse our lambda (GCMS will trigger the webhook once per create/update/delete operation)
    #  This makes sure only one instance of that lambda can run at once, to avoid refreshing the cache with parallel runs
    #  Avoid spawning tons of API calls (most of them would timeout anyway, around 80%)
    #  See https://itnext.io/the-everything-guide-to-lambda-throttling-reserved-concurrency-and-execution-limits-d64f144129e5
    reservedConcurrency: 1
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: /refresh-cache
          cors: true
```

The `refresh-cache` lambda was invoked by a webhook triggered by a third party service when any data change. When importing a dataset, it would for instance trigger as much as 100 calls to `refresh-cache`. This behaviour was completely spamming my API, which in turn was running requests to other services in order to perform a cache invalidation.

Adding this single line improved the situation a lot, because only one instance of the lambda was running at once (no concurrent run), the number of calls was divided by ~10, instead of 50 calls to `refresh-cache`, it only triggered 3-4, and all those call worked (200 instead of 500 due to timeout issue).

Overall, pretty good. Not yet perfect for my workflow, but a step forward.

---

Not related, but I used https://epsagon.com/ which tremendously helped me figuring out what was happening on AWS Lambda. Here is what I got:

**Before** applying `reservedConcurrency` limit to the lambda:
[image]

You can see that most calls fail with timeout (30000ms), only the few first succeed because the lambda isn't overloaded yet.

**After** applying `reservedConcurrency` limit to the lambda:
[image]

You can see that all calls succeed, and they are much faster. No timeout.
Saves both money, and time.

---

> Using `reservedConcurrency` is not the only way to deal with this issue, there are many other, as @Rodrigo stated in his answer. But it's a working one, that may fit in your workflow. It's applied on the Lambda level, not on API Gateway (if I understand the docs correctly).